# How to call a web method async in ASP.NET (SharePoint behind)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, sharepoint-2013

Calling this async Web Method, I get a 500 error. Are there other ways to call a web method async?

Stacktrace:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Unknown web method SendMessage. Parameter name: methodName
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method
>   SendMessage. Parameter name: methodName
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Unknown web method SendMessage. Parameter name:
>   methodName]
>   System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState(Object
>   sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +728343
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +92    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248

ASPX Codebehind:

```
namespace Any.Contact
{
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Services;

    public partial class ContactFormPage : PublishingLayoutPage
    {    
        [WebMethod]
        public static async Task<bool> SendMessage(string topic, string message)
        {
            return await SendEmail(topic, message);
        }
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: window.location.href + "/SendMessage",
  data: {
    "topic": jQuery('.ddl-topic').val(),
    "message": jQuery('.tb-message').val()
  },
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  async: true,
  cache: false,
  success: function() {
    $('.alert.alert-success').toggleClass('hidden', 'show');
  },
  error: function() {
    $('.alert.alert-danger').toggleClass('hidden', 'show');
  }
});
```

Comment: In addition to that answer, you'll probably also have to remove the `static` keyword from your method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Task, it'll be called asynchronous from JS. It can be regular method that returns bool.
Try:

```
namespace Any.Contact
{
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Services;

    public partial class ContactFormPage : PublishingLayoutPage
    {    
        [WebMethod]
        public static bool SendMessage(string topic, string message)
        {
            return SendEmail(topic, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was my answer useful?